# Vim macro expression to Emacs keyboard macro as a function with a key binding

Tags: json, command-line, emacs

I want to transform a whole bunch of JSON and lines like this:

```
"url": "https://my.favorite.bookmark.com",
"url": "https://yet.another.favorite.bookmark.com
```

One way I can do it is with `jq`. One way I can do it is with `grep`. One way I can do it is with Vim macros. But how would I do it with an Emacs keyboard macro?

I'm used to Vim macros and don't understand Emacs keyboard macros, which seem to be about code generation, which is way different. I might be missing a distinction between a "keyboard macro" and a "macro that generates code" here -- I'm pretty new to emacs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you're confusing Emacs-Lisp macros with Emacs keyboard macros. The latter are what you're apparently interested in. They essentially record your interactions (key presses, use of mouse, etc.) for later playback. And yes, you can bind a keyboard macro to a key, so that just hitting that key will play back what you recorded.

See the Emacs manual, node [Keyboard Macros](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Keyboard-Macros.html), for information about using keyboard macros.